# How to call a variable in post function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I call a variable (`t_d_url`) in a post function. It doesn't show the variable data. It shows only variable name.

I tried this way to call it:

```
$.post(t_d_url.'/ascott/includes/booking/booking-summary.php', {}, function(data) {
    $(".booking-summary").html(data);
});
```

Here is the variable:

`var t_d_url = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>';`

Here is the output:

[image: This is Error Result]

So I want to show this variable data in this function.

Comment: Why not directly doing `$.post('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>'+'/ascott/includes/booking/booking-summary.php',...`

Comment: That's more complex to read the code later..

Comment: if using js  can you not use '+' sign instead of '.' operator

Comment: Yeah... He is following PHP syntax

Comment: You should learn to properly use AJAX in WP. Just to make sure you keep everything safe and working properly. https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `.` to merge 2 strings. That only works in PHP. In Javascript you should use  `+`..

```
$.post(t_d_url+'/ascott/includes/booking/booking-summary.php', {}, function(data) {
    $(".booking-summary").html(data);
})
```

Comment: Thank you @r-pelzer to remove those tabs.

Comment: Sorry, I mistake the less url. Now, this is working. Thanks for this.....Just only change the `.` to `+`

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect concatination operator. `.` doesn't work with `Javascript` try using `+` as

```
let url = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/ascott/includes/booking/booking-summary.php";
$.post(url, {}, function(data){  $(".booking-summary").html(data);});
```

> In worst case, this will call `/ascott/includes/booking/booking-summary.php` on current domain

Answer (score 0):

You can use anyone of the following two method. Using `+` in JavaScript, because `JS` Doesn't merge strings using dot(`.`):

```
$.post(t_d_url+'/ascott/includes/booking/booking-summary.php', {}, function(data) {
                $(".booking-summary").html(data);
            })
```

Using `PHP` tag

```
$.post('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>'+'/ascott/includes/booking/booking-summary.php', {}, function(data) {
                    $(".booking-summary").html(data);
                })
```